Why is lazy-loading not working? Angular 17
I'm trying to create admin panel with lazy-loading. I created path /admin, but when i move to it, nothing happens. It goes to '/' path and shows nothing.
app.routes.ts
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './component/login/login.component';
import { NotFoundComponent } from './component/not-found/not-found.component';


export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
    },
    {
        path: '', 
        redirectTo: '/login', 
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'admin',
        loadChildren: () => import('./component/admin/admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule)
    },
    {
        path: '**', 
        component: NotFoundComponent
    }
    
];

admin.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AdminRoutingModule } from './admin-routing.module';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AdminRoutingModule,
  ]
})
export class AdminModule { }


admin-routing.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AdminDashboardComponent } from './Components/admin-dashboard/admin-dashboard.component';
import { ContactsComponent } from './Components/contacts/contacts.component';
import { ContactsDetailsComponent } from './Components/contacts-details/contacts-details.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './Components/home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: "", component: AdminDashboardComponent, children: [
    {path: 'contacts', component: ContactsComponent},
    {path: 'contacts/user/:id', component: ContactsDetailsComponent},
    {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
  ]},
  {}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AdminRoutingModule { }

Can you please help me to figure out what is the problem.

Can you check is there any error in console.
and can you please check in which module you have declared AdminDashboardComponent.
If you didn't declared it anywhere then please declare it in AdminModule
admin.module.ts
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AdminDashboardComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AdminRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class AdminModule { }

You also have to use router-outlet in AdminDashboardComponent.
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>


Thanks for the tip! I deleted the parameter :
standalone: true
in AdminDashboardComponent and it started working
